# How to find sum of dynamic inputs in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

//this is api response
{
"message": "success",
"code": 100,
"data": {
"inCourseCategories": [
{
"_id": "62b842f09184bf2330e6f506",
"course": "601a67e6db65fb15946e6b6f",
"title": "test in 1 update",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "62b8566d9184bf2330e6f6a6",
"course": "601a67e6db65fb15946e6b6f",
"title": "test 3update",
"__v": 0
}
],
"responseCode": 109
}
}
Below is my code:
I need sum of the inputs, also the default values and sum must be 0

//html code
//incoursedetails = response.data.inCourseCategories

```
{incoursedetails && incoursedetails.map((item,index)=>
                    <div className='justify-btw mb-2'>
                      <p>{item.title}</p><input onChange={(e)=>handleInScoreChange(e,index)} [enter image description here][1] className='score-input form-control' type="text" name="" id="" />
                    </div>)}

<p className='fw-500'>Score Category</p><p className='text-black'>20</p>  //display sum


const handleInScoreChange = (e , index)=>{
 //what to do here, please help
}
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW1ys.png
```

Comment: Can You explain your question a little bit more?

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002). But basically you've got some inputs and when they change you want the value of `sum` to be updated?

Comment: @Andy Yes, I need to find the sum and also update it, so that later i can pass the sum to backend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [use state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for this - rather two states: one for the sum, and one for the inputs as you change their values. You'll also need to [use the useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) so that when the input object changes you can change the `sum` state.

Note: I've used a separate `Field` component but you may not need to do that - but it's the "React Way".

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example({ data }) {

  // Initalise your states. `sum` has an initial
  // value of zero, and your inputs state is an
  // empty object
  const [ sum, setSum ] = useState(0);
  const [ inputs, setInputs ] = useState({});

  // When `getSum` is called get the values
  // of each property in the `inputs` state, `reduce`
  // them down, and then set the `sum` state
  function getSum() {
    const values = Object.values(inputs);
    const sum = values.reduce((acc, c) => acc + c, 0);
    setSum(sum);
  }

  // This gets called when any of the input values
  // change. It gets the name and value from the input,
  // and then updates the `inputs` state with that information
  function handleInput(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setInputs({ ...inputs, [name]: +value });
  }

  // When `inputs` changes call `getSum`
  useEffect(() => getSum(), [inputs]);

  // `map` over the data. Grab the id and title
  // from each object and then return a new Field
  // for each passing in the current input value, the
  // title, and the `handleInput` handler
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(obj => {
        const { id, title } = obj;
        return (
          <Field
            key={id}
            type="number"
            title={title}
            value={inputs[id]}
            handleInput={handleInput}
          />
        );
      })}
      <div className="sum">Sum: {sum}</div>
    </div>
  );

}

// `Field` simply builds up
// a little fieldset with a title, and
// an input
function Field(props) {
  
  const {
    value,
    type,
    title,
    handleInput
  } = props;
  
  return (
    <fieldset>
      <legend>{title}</legend>
      <input
        type={type}
        name={title}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleInput}
      />
    </fieldset>
  );

}

const data=[{_id:"62b842f09184bf2330e6f506",course:"601a67e6db65fb15946e6b6f",title:"test in 1 update",__v:0},{_id:"62b8566d9184bf2330e6f6a6",course:"601a67e6db65fb15946e6b6f",title:"test 3update",__v:0}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
fieldset { display: inline; padding: 0.5em; background-color: #efefef;}
input { margin: 0.5em 0; padding: 0.2em 0; }
legend { text-transform: uppercase; }
.sum { font-size: 1.3em; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)